# UnboundLocalError when applying a custom function with multiple arguments to a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm practicing to get a pandas series from this data by applying a function with multiple arguments.  My codes and data are the following

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def getage(x,now,status):
    if x != None:
        date = pd.to_datetime(x,format='%d%m%Y').date()
        age = relativedelta(now, date).years
        if status:
            age = relativedelta(now, date).years
        else:
            age = 'Unknown'
    return age

today = datetime.now().date()
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['001','002','003'],
                   'BirthDate':['25031978',None,'12122012'],
                   'Values':[5,10,15]})
customer_age = df['BirthDate'].apply(getage,args=(today,True,))
```

So, my data look like this

```
Index   BirthDate   ID   Values
0       25031978    001   5
1       None        002   10
3       12122012    003   15
```

After applying the getage function to the column 'BirthDate', I would like to get a pandas series (customer_age) as follows:

```
Index   0
0      38       # because the date difference (year) between BirthDate and today is 38
1      Unknown
2      4        # because the date difference (year) between BirthDate and today is 4
```

However, I get an error as follows:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'age' referenced before assignment
```

May I have your suggestions to fix this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `x` is `None`, you're still trying to return `age`. What's `age` when `x` is `None`?

Comment: The traceback showed you which line had the problem. If you posted the traceback we could see it too, but since you want us to guess, I'll guess. `UnboundLocalError` means that you tried to use a local variable before you assigned anything to it. Looking at your code, that will happen at `return age` when `x` is `None`. All I did was look back from the line with the error to any code paths that neglected to set `age`. The solution is an `else` clause to assign some value to `age` in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand much better about UnderboundlocalError and can fix it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2357112 pointed out, you need to set a value for age when x is 1. You can do that by adding another condition.

```
def getage(x,now,status):
    if x != None:
        date = pd.to_datetime(x,format='%d%m%Y').date()
        age = relativedelta(now, date).years
        if status:
            age = relativedelta(now, date).years

    if x == None or not status: # accounts for when x is None
       age = 'Unknown'
    return age
```